# How to display Animated GIF using PIL?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw,ImageFont
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
Width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
Height = GetSystemMetrics(1)
im = Image.new("RGB",(Width,Height),"white")
img = Image.open('images/text.gif', 'r')
im.paste(img,(420,600))
im.show()
```

Here the image displayed is static(just one instance of text.gif is displayed).Is there any way to display animated gif in pil? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the tkinter question. The tkinter question is specifically about tkinter, while here you can make no assumption as to what toolkit library is available or should be used. The OP is likely just looking for an `im.show()` equivalent that allows to animate the image.

Comment: Exactly,that's what I wanted to know . Thank you :-)

Comment: `img = Image.open('images/text.gif', 'r')
seq =  []
try:
    while 1:
        seq.append(img.copy())
        img.seek(len(seq)) # skip to next frame

except EOFError:
          pass

for frame in seq:
         im.paste(frame)
         im.show()`